# Differential equation of 3rd order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need some help solving the differential equation $$y'''=x+y\\   y(1)=3\\  y'(1)=2\\  y''(1)=1 $$ and $h=0.5$  with Euler's method

I don't know how to rewrite the equation to a system of equations of the first order..

Thanks!

Comment: A quick search and I found wikipedia which explains it quite well : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you linearize the system, we are given:

$$y'''(x) = x + y , y(1)=3,  y'(1)=2,  y''(1)=1$$

We can proceed as follows:

- $x_1 = y \implies x_1' = y' = x_2$
- $x_2 = y' \implies x_2' = y'' = x_3$
- $x_3 = y'' \implies x_3' = y''' = x + y = x + x_1$

So, our new system is:

$$\begin{align}
x_1' & = x_2 \\
x_2' & = x_3 \\
x_3' & = x + x_1
\end{align}$$

Note, the given initial conditions, similarly follow as:

- $y(1) = 3 \implies x_1(1) = 3$
- $y'(1) = 2 \implies x_2(1) = 2$
- $y''(1) =1 \implies x_3(1) = 1$

Now, apply Euler's method to this system using $h = 0.5$.